# Using svelte derived store with dexie liveQuery

Tags: svelte, dexie

I am using Dexie.js with svelte in a SPA my current setup is the following :

- Dexies calls are grouped in repos
- DB updates are watched with dexie liveQuery
- Svelte derived stores make the bridge between the liveQuery and the App

Thanks to this the view don't have to know which ORM I am using or even if I am using one, I can change the database values before they reach the views (for exemple adding default and computed values). Here's what it's look like for the stores part :

```
 export const categories = derived(
   liveQuery(getAllCategories),
   $categories => {
     $categories = $categories || [];
     $categories.unshift(new Category(null, "None", "#DDD"));
     return $categories;
   }
 );
```

With `getAllCategories` a Dexie call to the database. It's all good and working but I have the following problem : `liveQuery(getAllCategories)` will always return undefined **once** at the start of the app, probably because of the async call to the database ?

Also, in simple case I want to override the `set` method of the store to update back the database when the store is updated. But with my current setup I didn't find anything that make it possible to override `set` in a derived store, which would make sense since derived is kinda computed but I am still looking for a way to do that.